# Error handeling w/ form_for in associated resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling

I can't seem to get the flow to work right here. I have a Ruby on Rails (2.3.9) application. For the purposes of this question we have only a couple of resources. `Boxes` and `Messages`.

```
Box has_many :messages
Message belongs_to :box
```

I have created a view located at `/boxes/1/new_message` where I have the below form_for code. I can successfully create a message from this view. The problem arrises when my validations kick in.

In this case, `message.body` can't be blank and is validated by `message.rb`. Once this validation happens, it kicks the user over to the Message.new action and upon successfully filling in the `message.body` the app can no longer find the `@box.id` to place in `message.box_id`.

I have tried just about everything I can think of by not sure how to allow a users to receive a validation and still successfully create a message for a box. See my code below for reference.

/views/boxes/new_message.html.erb

```
<% form_for [@box, Message.new] do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <%= f.label :message_title %>
  <%= f.text_field (:title, :class => "textfield-message grid_12 alpha") %>

  <%= f.label :message_body %>
  <%= f.text_area (:body, :class => "textarea-message grid_12 alpha ") %>

  <%= f.submit "Add a Message", :class => 'input boxy' %>       
<% end %>
```

messages_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    @box = Box.find(params[:box_id])
    @message = @box.messages.build(params[:message])
    @message.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Message was successfully created.'
        format.html {redirect_to @box }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @flash.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @message }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your

```
@box = Box.find(params[:box_id])
```

should be

```
@box = Box.find(params[:id])
```